# Dojo FilteringSelect: default value on async. store not visible

Tags: javascript, dojo

It seems that the default value for a dijit.form.FilteringSelect does not show on load, or when the store gets applied.

I have created a fiddle to illustrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/NiekVandael/2nmz8433/3/

```
var fs = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    store: getMyStore(),
    value: "Bar" /* Bar should be the default value */
}, 'fsNode');
```

Documentation:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html

Any toughts?

Niek

Comment: have you called `fs.startup()`?

Answer (score 1):

have you called `fs.startup()`?.

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/f1t4w7qz/1/) with startup called.

**edit1:**

In order to set the default value you need to set the value attribute to the store **Identifier** field and not the display value.

```
var fs = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
        store: getMyStore(),
        value: 0 /* 0 is the identifier for the default 'Loading, Please wait 3 seconds...' will be show.n */
    }, 'fsNode');
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/f1t4w7qz/2/).

Remember that the default value will be shown only once at the first time of starting up the FilteringSelect widget.

The value 'Bar' that you would like to show as default is not available at the startup. It is available only after the setTimeout function is executed. Hence it cannot be shown at the startup.

**edit2:**

You can set the value of the FilteringSelect widget by using the **set()** function of the widget.
check the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/f1t4w7qz/4/)

Comment: Frank, thanks for your answer. I agree to call the startup() function, but I cannot see the default value appearing in the Dojo FilteringSelect in your fiddle?

Comment: just try it will a longer delay about 9 seconds ( 9000 ) in the setTimeout. and then click the filtering select you will see the default value i.e. `Loading, Please wait 3 seconds...`

Comment: Yes, but i want to display a default value without clicking the filteringselect. I want a value like "Bar" to get displayed into the filteringselect as 'selected value' before the store loads.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for putting your time in this question. I can now see that 'loading please wait' is set als default when i run the app, and that's a beginning! But I want 'Bar' as default selection, not 'loading please wait'. It would be an issue for us, if this cannot be done... Maybe you have some suggestions or workarounds?